# python 3 https posting very slow

Tags: python, http, post, python-3.x, urllib

I have a script which logs in via https using python 3 and FancyURLopener.
So I am doing this:

```
from urllib.request import FancyURLopener, urlopen
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import re, sys

class SMS:

    login_url = "url1"
    login_act = "url2"
    comp_url = "url3"
    comp_act = "url4"
    LEN = 100

    def __init__(self, phone_num, password):
        self.phone_num = phone_num
        self.password = password
        self.opener = FancyURLopener()
        resp = self.opener.open(SMS.login_url)
        cookie = ""
        for x, y in resp.headers.items():
            if x == "Set-Cookie":
                cookie += y + "; "
        cookie = cookie[:-2]            
        self.opener.addheader("Cookie", cookie)
        print("--login")
        self.login()

    def login(self):
        di = { "action":"", "refid":"", "continuation":"",\
"username":self.phone_num, "password":self.password, "image.x":"45", "image.y":"18"}
        resp = self.opener.open(SMS.login_act, urlencode(di))

    def send(self, to, message):
        print("--sending")
        if len(message) > 100:
            print("Message length too long; Not send.")
            return -1
        resp = self.opener.open(SMS.comp_url).read().decode("windows-1251")
        pattern1 = "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"daycreditsmsleft\" value=\"(\d+)\""
        pattern2 = "<input type=\"HIDDEN\" name=\"smssenttime\" value=\"(\d+)\""
        post = {"brand":"", "daycreditsmsleft":re.search(pattern1, resp).groups()[0],\
"process":"true", "btnSendSMS.x":"75", "btnSendSMS.y":"23", "model":"0",\
"smssenttime":re.search(pattern2, resp).groups()[0], "remainingChars": str(SMS.LEN - len(message)),\
"reply2inbox":"false", "selReceiverName":"", "txtareaMessage":message, "receiverPhoneNum":to}
        if post["daycreditsmsleft"] == 0:
            print("No more messages; Not send")
            return -1
        resp = self.opener.open(SMS.comp_act, urlencode(post) )
```

I will then use it like this:

```
s = SMS("telephone_num", "pass")
s.send(tel, message)
```

The problem is that the POST request is too slow. It takes more than 20 seconds to log in.
In the whole script there are 2 POST requests so it actually runs near a minute. How to optimize it?

I also noticed that the messages are received before the program ends.

Comment: "too slow"?  Have you tried to log in manually (using a browser)?  Is that any faster?  How much faster?  Can you post time comparison between manual and `urllib`?

Comment: If at all possible, please provide all details (example cookie, username, password and url) to reproduce this. The problem might not lie in the code you've provided and I have a suspicion this might go by unanswered as is.

Comment: Using browser it logs immediately. I'll add all code.

Comment: "immediately"?  Can you attempt to measure it?  Note that there are two page loads involved in your code, you need to measure both.  The page that shows the login form and the page you get after the login.  This is -- admittedly -- hard to measure because you have to type and click (or paste and click, or wait for your browser to auto-fill the fields).

Comment: using Firebug when login: 1.99s (onload 2.35), using urllib manually: ~21 sec. That is only for login. The other request from browser is 2.13, again urllib: ~21 sec. And the strange thing is that the message is received almost immediately (~1-2 sec) after my program prints "--sending" but then it halts.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that there is something subtly different in the requests, that make your server take a very long time in processing the request.

If you are the writer of the server, this should be easy to verify. If not you probably have to use some sort of tracing program so you can see when the request is done from the Python-side and seeing when a response comes back, and comparing that with a request from your browser.

Comment: I suspect that the problem is with my program because I receive the messages before the python program stops.

Comment: @cldy: I don't really know what that means. What is "I" in the above sentence? These 20 seconds, when do they happen really? Before Python sends the request? Between the request and the response? After the response?

Comment: I mean that I receive the message on my phone. This script logs in on a webpage, post some data and then I receive SMS. So I receive the SMS 2 seconds after I send the second post, but in my python script it waits for `resp` for 19 more.

Comment: @cldy: Then it's clear that it's the server that takes time, and it has nothing to do with https posting in Python, and so my guess was correct.